# Proof $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\sin(x))^n dx = \frac{n-1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\sin(x))^{n-2} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I proof that
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\sin(x))^n dx  =
\frac{n-1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\sin(x))^{n-2} dx 
$$
for  $n\geq 2$

I have tried integration by parts but I couldn't get it to look anything like the integral from above.

Comment: are you sure it's not $n(n-1)$?

Comment: @Alex Yes I am sure.

Comment: For short: integration by parts. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts to obtain

\begin{align}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^nx \, dx& = -\sin^{n-1}x \cos x\bigg|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} +\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x \cdot (n-1)\sin^{n-2} x\cos x\, dx\\
&= (n-1)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2} x \cos^2 x\, dx\\
&= (n-1)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\sin^{n-2}x - \sin^n x)\, dx\\
&= (n-1)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^{n-2}x - (n-1)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^n x\, dx
\end{align}

Thus

$$n\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^n x\, dx = (n-1)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}x\, dx,$$

or

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\, dx = \frac{n-1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}x\, dx.$$

Comment: How did you conclude that $\begin{align}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^nx \, dx& = -\sin^{n-1}x \cos x\bigg|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} +\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x \cdot (n-1)\sin^{n-2} x\cos x\, dx\\
\end{align}$? By using integration by parts? What was your $u$ and $dv$?

Comment: @MaikKlein $u = \sin^{n-1} x$ and $dv = \sin x\, dx$.

Answer (score 0):

If n is odd,then
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}xdx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}xdx=0$$

If n is even,then
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}xdx=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}xdx$$
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x\cos^{2n-1}xdx=B(m,n)$$
Proof:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1}x\cos^{2n-1}xdx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-2}x\cos^{2n-2}x\sin x\cos xdx$$
By substituting $t=\sin^2x$ and $dt=2\sin x\cos x$,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-2}x\cos^{2n-2}\sin x\cos xxdx=\frac12\int_0^1 t^{m-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt=\frac12B(m,n)$$

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}xdx=B(\frac{1+n}{2},\frac12)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1+n}{2})\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(1+\frac{n}2)}=\frac{\frac{n-1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}2)}$$
$$\therefore\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}xdx=\frac{n-1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}xdx$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this presupposes the result (essentially, the beta function formula) that OP is working towards proving.